# Extremely slow object instantiation in Python 2.7

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, overhead

I recently had to complete an assignment that used a lot of coordinate operations.  Thinking to save time and simplify my code, I defined a class to encapsulate the behaviour of a coordinate pair.  The class looked like this:

```
class Vector (tuple) :
    def __init__ (self, value) :
        tuple.__init__ (self, value)


    def __add__ (self, other) :
        return Vector ((self [0] + other [0], self [1] + other [1]))
```

This allowed me to write code like this (for example):

```
def translate (pointList, displacement) :
    return [point + displacement for point in pointList]
```

But my application was terribly slow.  Much slower than other assignments.  I couldn't locate any inefficiency in my implementation of the algorithm, so I did a simple test to see what the overhead was of the Vector class.  I expected somewhere between 5% and 15%.

My test of the Vector class looked like this:

```
v = Vector ((0, 0))
d = Vector ((1, -1))
loopIdx = 3000000
while loopIdx > 0 :
    v = v + d
    loopIdx -= 1
print (v)
```

This runs (typically) in this kind of time:

```
real    0m8.440s
user    0m8.367s
sys     0m0.016s
```

For comparison I ran this code:

```
v = (0, 0)
dX = 1
dY = -1
loopIdx = 3000000
while loopIdx > 0 :
    v = ( v [0] + dX, v [1] + dY )
    loopIdx -= 1
print (v)
```

Run time for this code is:

```
real    0m1.004s
user    0m0.995s
sys     0m0.006s
```

Have I done something seriously wrong, or does using class objects in Python really mean your application will take over 8 times as long to run?

Comment: It's probably not the class itself, more that tuple is implemented directly in C whereas your class is not.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but: Instead of your `Vector` class, you could just use `complex` numbers to represent 2D coordinates. Addition, substration, absolute value (for distance) etc. included. Also, that's another 2-3 times faster than using tuples as in your second approach.

Comment: You could consider a class with `__slots__` to minimise the memory footprint of each instance.

Comment: Just dropping `__init__` changes nothing in semantics, but speeds up your test with the class by 60%.

Comment: Using `complex` seems very promising.  I would like to add other behaviour that is used less often, such as applying a rotation transform.  Could I subclass `complex`, @tobias_k?  What would I use instead of `tuple.__init__ (self, value)` to call the super constructor?  Perhaps you could post it as an answer if it's not too much trouble.  Please?

Comment: Another point why class is slower: `d` is not optimized away as a constant, while `dX`/`dY` are, even if you put them in a tuple. So, with class it has to evaluate `d[0]` in addition all the times, while without class it is just addition of a constant number.

Comment: You can "rotate" complex numbers by multiplying them by another complex number with absolute value 1. But does this have to be a method of the class itself? You could just make this a helper function.

Comment: Good point @doublep, that's going to skew my test results.  I'll see if I can construct a test that won't optimise the operands.

Comment: A helper function would certainly work @tobias_k, but I would have to go through my application and back-engineer all my beautiful OO method calls away.

Comment: I don't think what you use instead `tuple.__init__` matters. It's just that if you don't have an `__init__` method, Python reuses its internal fast code for allocating tuple objects. Else it falls back on generic (and slow) method for allocating arbitrary Python objects.

Comment: The problem is: If you create a subclass of `complex` just for the rotate function, you have to overwrite all the other methods, too, to return your subclass instead of a regular `complex`. Given the massive speed up, I think this is a compromise you should accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer how to make you class faster, but more of an alternative.

Instead of subclassing `tuple` and writing all those `add`, `sub` etc. methods yourself, you cold just use Python's bultin `complex` number type for 2D coordinates, which has all those operations already built in, correct and and super-fast.

```
>>> %timeit vector_no_init()
1 loops, best of 3: 1.39 s per loop
>>> %timeit plain_tuple()
1 loops, best of 3: 403 ms per loop
>>> %timeit complex_nums()
1 loops, best of 3: 171 ms per loop
```

For rotation, you can use complex multiplication: Just multiply your complex coordinate with a complex number that has, in polar form, absolute value 1 and a phase equal to the angle you want to rotate by. 
To rotate by 90 degrees, you can just multiply by `1j` (anti-clockwise) or `-1j` (clockwise). For all other angles, use the [`cmath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) module for translation to and from polar form.

```
>>> c = complex(4, 2)
>>> c * cmath.rect(1, math.radians(45))
(1.4142135623730954+4.242640687119285j)
```

However, I would suggest *not* to subclass `complex` to make `rotate` a method of that class, because in this case you will have to overwrite all the other methods, like `add`, as well, otherwise the result of addition will be a regular complex number, not providing the `rotate` method. And this would undo all those performance gains, making it just as slow as your `Vector` class. Instead, just make a function `rotate(complex, angle) -> complex`.

Comment: Thank you.  As a preliminary result, using `complex` to replace the `tuple` raw arithmetic (no class), produces a performance improvement of 40%.